# Can't extract clusters from fcluster after using scipy's hierarchichal clustering

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

After doing hierarchichal clustering on my dataset and plotting it with dendrogram function it seems that it was correct clustered, but when I call function fcluster to extract the cluster ids I just get one cluster id, ever.
Why is this happening?

My code:

```
    for key, values in use_case_idx.items():
        vectors = []
        labels = []
        for value in values:
            labels.append(value[0])
            vectors.append(value[1])

        try:
            distance_matrix = pdist(vectors, metric='cosine')
            Z = linkage(distance_matrix, 'ward')
            plt.title("Ward")
            dendrogram(Z, labels=labels)
        except:
            continue

        plt.show()

        clusters = fcluster(Z, 10, criterion='distance')
        print(clusters)
```

And thus, the output:

[image]

[image]

More examples on: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33ojS.jpg

What's wrong with this code?

Note: Each vector has 50 dimensions

Comment: Don't just use some value like `10`. You need to choose this parameter.

Comment: I didn't. I was just wrong about the intention of it. I thought it was a limit of max clusters.

Comment: See the fcluster documentation, the meaning depends on the `criterion` you choose!

Answer (score 1):

The y-axis of the dendrogram shows the [cophenetic distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cophenetic) between different nodes. Because you are using the `distance` criterion with a large value (much larger than the cophenetic distance), all elements are grouped into the same cluster.

Try using a smaller threshold (e.g. 0.025 for the first dendrogram you show). The dendrogram can act as a guide to choose "good" thresholds---although "good" is very subjective.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the paremeter t from fcluster was just a control of the number of max clusters. I think that the documentation is not very clear. Just to clarify, the parameter that you advises to change is the 't' from fcluster, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cluster your data into n distinct clusters you can do this using the criterion 'maxclust' so for example fcluster(data,n,criterion = 'maxclust')